# How to I extract time from sentence and transform into number?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Can I use this method to extract the timelines from this string:

```
1 month in role 1 year 11 months in company
```

and transform them into a number of months?

E.g

1 month = 1 
1 year 11 months = 23

Any help greatly appreciated!

Have tried the =split formula but all sentences are slightly different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: 0]

formula in **B2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "role"), 
 IF(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(year|mont)")="mont", REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+"),
 IF(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(year|mont)")="year", REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+")*12+
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\d+) mont")), )), )))
```

formula in **C2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 IF(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "role (.+)"), "(year|mont)")="mont",
 REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "role (.+)"), "\d+"),
 IF(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "role (.+)"), "(year|mont)")="year",
 REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "role (.+)"), "\d+")*12+
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "role (.+)"), "(\d+) mont")), )), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "company"), 
 IF(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(year|mont)")="mont", REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+"),
 IF(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(year|mont)")="year", REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+")*12+
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\d+) mont")), )), )))
```

Comment: Thanks @player0, that worked exactly the way I was looking for! Also thanks for adding in the variations!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using regular expressions.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\d+ years? (\d+ months? )?in company)"), " "), 0, 1), 0) * 12 + IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\d+ months? in company)"), " "), 0, 1), 0)
```

(A1 in the formula above represents the cell containing the timeline string. This would need to be adjusted as needed)

Basically, this formula looks for "x year(s) (x month(s) )in company" If such a string is found, it will split it up by spaces and take the first portion (the x in x years). If no such pattern is found (for example, when the string is "1 month in role 1 month in company") then the year part is ignored.

For robustness, it is necessary to check if the the year is followed by an optional month component, then "in company." Otherwise, "1 year 1 month in role 2 years 11 months in company" would return 1 for the year, which is not what we want.

The second part of the formula looks for "x month(s) in company" If not found, then the month portion is ignored (e.g. "1 year in role 1 year in company")